# How to make responsive table

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a table to represent some data in my html page. I'm trying to make this table as responsive. How can I do this?

Here is the [`Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/tvbishan/XYbwW/).

Comment: try this https://www.google.com/search?q=Responsive+table

Comment: max-width does interesting things, it's similar to width, but it will let the table become tighter if screen is tighter.

Comment: The time for flexbox is on it's way. http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: Yes, agree with @Toskan. With flexbox you can do really interesting things, if you don't mind replacing semantic tables with divs. Checkout [Really Responsive Tables using Flexbox](https://hashnode.com/post/really-responsive-tables-using-css3-flexbox-cijzbxd8n00pwvm53sl4l42cx) and associated code pens.

Comment: nice simple example here: https://jsfiddle.net/zinoui/tfc0s2mv/ . Only requires to copy some CSS and set class names at the `<table>` tag

Answer (score 48, accepted):

### Basically

A responsive table is simply a 100% width table.

You can just set up your table with this CSS:

```css
.table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table class="table" border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Table head</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

You can use media queries to show/hide/manipulate columns according to the screens dimensions by adding a class (or targeting using `nth-child`, etc):

```
/* When the screen size is bigger than 320px hide the element */
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    .hide { display: none; }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<td class="hide">Not important</td>
```

### More advanced solutions

If you have a table with a lot of data and you would like to make it readable on small screen devices there are many other solutions:

- css-tricks.com offers up [this article](http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/) for handling large data tables.
- Zurb also ran into this issue and [solved it](http://zurb.com/playground/responsive-tables) using javascript.
- [Footables](https://fooplugins.com/plugins/footable-jquery/) is a great jQuery plugin that also helps you out with this issue.
- As posted by [Elvin Arzumanoğlu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1368240/elvin-arzumanoglu) this is a great [list of examples](http://elvery.net/demo/responsive-tables).

Comment: There is no any **Magic** as i thought. I have copied my normal `CSS` code for table into `@media{}` and change parameters to compatible with mobile screens. It's worked. I think it is correct. Here is the [Demo](http://jsbin.com/EvOZoyE/1/). is that correct ? thanks for your answer. :)

Comment: @Bishan The demo looks good to me. Although you should only keep the code that manipulates the element.

Comment: Sorry. `manipulates the element` means ?

Comment: @Bishan It means only the css that `changes the table`. So, don't just copy paste all your css code and change it. Copy only the parts that you need for the mobile version.

Comment: Also using `table-layout: fixed` might help a lot.

Answer (score 16):

Check the below links for responsive table:

http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/

http://zurb.com/playground/responsive-tables

http://zurb.com/playground/projects/responsive-tables/index.html

Answer (score 4):

You can view this [Demo](http://elvery.net/demo/responsive-tables/#) or [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive)

Answer (score 1):

If you want control over the td's/th's like you can do with block level elements & floats:
Its NOT possible. 
There is no way to make a td float over or under a th.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the Wordpress plugin [Magic Liquidizer Responsive Table](http://wordpress.org/plugins/magic-liquidizer-responsive-table/).

Answer (score 0):

For make responsive table you can make 100% of each ‘td’ and insert related heading in the ‘td’ on the mobile(less the ’768px’ width).

See More:
http://wonderdesigners.com/?p=227

Answer (score -1):

Pure css way to make a table fully responsive, no JavaScript is needed. Checke demo here [Responsive Tables](http://a2znotes.blogspot.in/2014/08/making-table-fully-responsive.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE>
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>Responsive Table</title>
  <style> 
  /* only for demo purpose. you can remove it */
 .container{border: 1px solid #ccc; background-color: #ff0000; 
  margin: 10px auto;width: 98%; height:auto;padding:5px; text-align: center;}

 /* required */
.tablewrapper{width: 95%; overflow-y: hidden; overflow-x: auto; 
 background-color:green;  height: auto; padding: 5px;}

 /* only for demo purpose just for stlying. you can remove it */
 table { font-family: arial; font-size: 13px; padding: 2px 3px}
 table.responsive{ background-color:#1a99e6; border-collapse: collapse; 
 border-color: #fff}

tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-of-type(1){
 background:#333; color: #fff}
 tr:nth-child(1) td{
 background:#333; color: #fff; font-weight: bold;}
 table tr td:nth-child(2) {
 background:yellow;
}
 tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-of-type(2){color: #333}
 tr:nth-child(odd){ background:#ccc;}
 tr:nth-child(even){background:#fff;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="tablewrapper">
<table  class="responsive" width="98%" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="1" border="1">
 <tr> 
 <td>Name</td> 
 <td>Email</td> 
 <td>Phone</td> 
 <td>Address</td> 
 <td>Contact</td> 
 <td>Mobile</td> 
 <td>Office</td> 
 <td>Home</td> 
 <td>Residency</td> 
 <td>Height</td>
 <td>Weight</td>
 <td>Color</td> 
 <td>Desease</td> 
 <td>Extra</td>
 <td>DOB</td>
 <td>Nick Name</td> 
</tr>
<tr>  
<td>RN Kushwaha</td>
<td>rn.kushwaha@test.com</td>
<td>--</td>  
<td>Varanasi</td>
<td>-</td> 
<td>999999999</td> 
<td>022-111111</td> 
<td>-</td>
<td>India</td> 
<td>165cm</td> 
<td>58kg</td> 
<td>bright</td> 
<td>--</td> 
<td>--</td> 
<td>03/07/1986</td> 
<td>Aryan</td> 
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is only "responsive" in the barest sense of the word. It results in a table that must be scrolled horizontally when the viewport is too small. A truly responsive table would reformat so it would be entirely visible horizontally.

Comment: Going to the link and clicking live demo results in a 404.

Answer (score -2):

To make a responsive table, you can make the width of each `td`  100%  and insert a related heading in the `td` on  mobile browsers (that are less `768px` width.)

Here is a website that demonstrates this technique: `http://www.quizexpo.com/list-of-banks-in-india/`