# How to make a table responsive?

Tags: php, html, responsive-design

Given below is my table which i wanna make responsive.

```
 <table style="width:100%" class="table table-hover">

                <tr>
                    <th>Booking Date</th>
                    <th>Booking Id</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                    <th>Movie Name</th>
                    <th>Theatre Name</th>
                </tr>
                <?php
                    foreach ( $data as $history )
                    {
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td> <?php print_r( $history->booking_date );?></td>
                            <td> <?php print_r( $history->booking_id ); ?></td>
                            <td> <?php print_r( $history->amount ); ?></td>
                            <?php $movie = Movies::find()->where( [ 'id' => $history->movie_id ] )->one(); ?>
                            <td><?php print_r( $movie->movie_name ); ?></td>
                            <?php $theatre = Theatres::find()->where( [ 'id' => $history->theatre_id ] )->one();?>
                            <td><?php print_r( $theatre->theatre_name ); ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php
                    }
                ?>
  </table>
```

class="table table-hover" was used so that when i hover over the rows i get a
different color. I changed it to class="table table-responsive" but even then 
i found my table not responsive. What should i do to make it responsive?

Comment: a jquery bib?
works fine for me. http://zurb.com/playground/responsive-tables

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436864/how-to-make-responsive-table

Comment: Are you using any front-end framework? What is your CSS?

Comment: yes i am using Yii2 framework.

Comment: What do you expect `table-responsive` to make it responsive? Have you defined any CSS or JS that would apply to it? What do you mean by "responsive" anyway? It means "adapting to window size", but there are lots of ways you could do that, so by itself its as informative as "make it good".

Answer (score 0):

```css
<style type="text/css">
/* 
Generic Styling, for Desktops/Laptops 
*/
.table-hover { 
  width: 100%; 
  border-collapse: collapse; 
}
/* Zebra striping */
tr:nth-of-type(odd) { 
  background: #eee; 
}
th { 
  background: #333; 
  color: white; 
  font-weight: bold; 
}
td, th { 
  padding: 6px; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  text-align: left; 
}

tr:hover {
  background-color: lightyellow;
}

</style>
```

```html
<table class="table table-hover">

                <tr>
                    <th>Booking Date</th>
                    <th>Booking Id</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                    <th>Movie Name</th>
                    <th>Theatre Name</th>
                </tr>
                <?php
                    foreach ( $data as $history )
                    {
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td> <?php print_r( $history->booking_date );?></td>
                            <td> <?php print_r( $history->booking_id ); ?></td>
                            <td> <?php print_r( $history->amount ); ?></td>
                            <?php $movie = Movies::find()->where( [ 'id' => $history->movie_id ] )->one(); ?>
                            <td><?php print_r( $movie->movie_name ); ?></td>
                            <?php $theatre = Theatres::find()->where( [ 'id' => $history->theatre_id ] )->one();?>
                            <td><?php print_r( $theatre->theatre_name ); ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php
                    }
                ?>
  </table>
```

try this one

source: https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/