# formatting a list in rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

[image: Current Look]

I'm trying to format this list so that each individual section (name, diet, run #, and owner) are separated and have the same margins. I think I have to change something in `_patient.html.erb` but I'm not sure how.

My current `_patient.html.erb`

```
<li>
  <%= link_to patient.name + " #{patient.owner.last_name} ", patient %>
  <%= link_to patient.diet, patient, style: "color:red;" %>
  <% if patient.stays.length > 0 %>
      <%= Runn.find_by_id(patient.stays.last.runn_id).ident %> 
  <% end %> 
  (Owned by <%= link_to "#{patient.owner.first_name} #{patient.owner.last_name}", patient.owner %>)
</li>
```

this is `index.html.erb`

```
<h1>Patients</h1>
<div>
    <%= link_to "Generate Feed List", new_feed_list_path, class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary"%>
</div>

<% provide(:title, 'All patients') %>
<%= will_paginate %>
<ul class="patients">
  <%= render @patients %>
</ul>
<%= will_paginate %>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using a table?

Comment: It's my first rails project, so I'm learning as I go

Comment: I'll look into tables now

Comment: @Yang How will tables make it harder to be responsive? The OP seems to be using Bootstrap, which includes [responsive tables](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables). And even if you aren't using Bootstrap, [it's quite easy to make a table responsive](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18437686/2856441)

Comment: @JoeKennedy The principle of responsive table is hiding some of them when the screen is too small to display all the columns. Cannot shift them down like using `<div>`, `<span>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using an [HTML table](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp), rather than a list.

In `index.html.erb`, instead of `<ul>`:

```
<table class='patients'>
  <tbody>
     <%= render @patients %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Your new `_patient.html.erb` file:

```
<tr>
  <td>
     <%= link_to patient.name + " #{patient.owner.last_name} ", patient %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <%= link_to patient.diet, patient, style: "color:red;" %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <% if patient.stays.length > 0 %>
      <%= Runn.find_by_id(patient.stays.last.runn_id).ident %> 
    <% end %>
  </td>
  <td>
    (Owned by <%= link_to "#{patient.owner.first_name} #{patient.owner.last_name}", patient.owner %>)
  </td>
</tr>
```

I'd also recommend reading a bit more about tables, from the link I posted above.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. I will suggest you to add a class to your `<li>` like:

```
<li class="patient-item">
```

And change `margin` or whatever styles you want in your `css` file.

Comment: what do i have to add to my css file? something like this?

patinet-item {
 #margin stuff here
}