# Making HTML Table Responsive

Tags: html, html-table, responsive

I am trying to make this table responsive to re-sizing the browser and specifically to mobile devices. I have tried to make the width of the table tag 100%, but that affects the spacing of my image and text. Is there any other way to make this table responsive to where it does not affect the spacing of my images and text? Thank you very much for the responses in advance.

```html
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" style="width: 1000px;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
        <img alt="Logo" src="Logo.png" style="width: 120px; height: 100px;" />
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;">
        <b><i>
          Everyone is free to use the summary information. Please acknowledge 
          the Logo as the source of any information accessed from the site unless 
          otherwise noted.<br/>
        </i></b>
      </td>
      <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
        <img alt="Logo" src="Logo.png" style="width: 120px; height: 100px;" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You can try bootstrap class 'table-responsive' by wrapping the whole table inside a <div class="table-responsive"> </div>

Comment: Great, thank you so much. That worked!

Comment: You can also use media queries to adjust table column's width manually for each of your selected breakpoints if you do not want the horizontal scrolling feature provided by bootstrap . As for the images you can use bootstrap's class "img-responsive" just put it in the <img> tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make responsive table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436864/how-to-make-responsive-table)

Answer (score 1):

it might be possible to create by using inline-css so you can use `@media` query which will help you to make it responsive table. working example as below

```css
/*
 Max width before this PARTICULAR table gets nasty. This query will take effect for any screen smaller than 760px and also iPads specifically.
 */
 @media
   only screen 
    and (max-width: 760px), (min-device-width: 768px) 
    and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {

  /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
  table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr {
   display: block;
  }

  /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
  thead tr {
   position: absolute;
   top: -9999px;
   left: -9999px;
  }

    tr {
      margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
    }
      
    tr:nth-child(odd) {
      background: #ccc;
    }
    
  td {
   /* Behave  like a "row" */
   border: none;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
   position: relative;
   padding-left: 50%;
  }

  td:before {
   /* Now like a table header */
   position: absolute;
   /* Top/left values mimic padding */
   top: 0;
   left: 6px;
   width: 45%;
   padding-right: 10px;
   white-space: nowrap;
  }

  /*
  Label the data
    You could also use a data-* attribute and content for this. That way "bloats" the HTML, this way means you need to keep HTML and CSS in sync. Lea Verou has a clever way to handle with text-shadow.
  */
  td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "First Name"; }
  td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Last Name"; }
  td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Job Title"; }
  td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "Favorite Color"; }
  td:nth-of-type(5):before { content: "Wars of Trek?"; }
  td:nth-of-type(6):before { content: "Secret Alias"; }
  td:nth-of-type(7):before { content: "Date of Birth"; }
  td:nth-of-type(8):before { content: "Dream Vacation City"; }
  td:nth-of-type(9):before { content: "GPA"; }
  td:nth-of-type(10):before { content: "Arbitrary Data"; }
 }
```

```html
<table role="table">
  <thead role="rowgroup">
    <tr role="row">
      <th role="columnheader">First Name</th>
      <th role="columnheader">Last Name</th>
      <th role="columnheader">Job Title</th>
      <th role="columnheader">Favorite Color</th>
      <th role="columnheader">Wars or Trek?</th>
      <th role="columnheader">Secret Alias</th>
      <th role="columnheader">Date of Birth</th>
      <th role="columnheader">Dream Vacation City</th>
      <th role="columnheader">GPA</th>
      <th role="columnheader">Arbitrary Data</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody role="rowgroup">
    <tr role="row">
      <td role="cell">James</td>
      <td role="cell">Matman</td>
      <td role="cell">Chief Sandwich Eater</td>
      <td role="cell">Lettuce Green</td>
      <td role="cell">Trek</td>
      <td role="cell">Digby Green</td>
      <td role="cell">January 13, 1979</td>
      <td role="cell">Gotham City</td>
      <td role="cell">3.1</td>
      <td role="cell">RBX-12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row">
      <td role="cell">The</td>
      <td role="cell">Tick</td>
      <td role="cell">Crimefighter Sorta</td>
      <td role="cell">Blue</td>
      <td role="cell">Wars</td>
      <td role="cell">John Smith</td>
      <td role="cell">July 19, 1968</td>
      <td role="cell">Athens</td>
      <td role="cell">N/A</td>
      <td role="cell">Edlund, Ben (July 1996).</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row">
      <td role="cell">Jokey</td>
      <td role="cell">Smurf</td>
      <td role="cell">Giving Exploding Presents</td>
      <td role="cell">Smurflow</td>
      <td role="cell">Smurf</td>
      <td role="cell">Smurflane Smurfmutt</td>
      <td role="cell">Smurfuary Smurfteenth, 1945</td>
      <td role="cell">New Smurf City</td>
      <td role="cell">4.Smurf</td>
      <td role="cell">One</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row">
      <td role="cell">Cindy</td>
      <td role="cell">Beyler</td>
      <td role="cell">Sales Representative</td>
      <td role="cell">Red</td>
      <td role="cell">Wars</td>
      <td role="cell">Lori Quivey</td>
      <td role="cell">July 5, 1956</td>
      <td role="cell">Paris</td>
      <td role="cell">3.4</td>
      <td role="cell">3451</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row">
      <td role="cell">Captain</td>
      <td role="cell">Cool</td>
      <td role="cell">Tree Crusher</td>
      <td role="cell">Blue</td>
      <td role="cell">Wars</td>
      <td role="cell">Steve 42nd</td>
      <td role="cell">December 13, 1982</td>
      <td role="cell">Las Vegas</td>
      <td role="cell">1.9</td>
      <td role="cell">Under the couch</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Bootstrap to make responsive web pages.

There are different class available which will take care of responsiveness.

If you don't want to use bootstrap then you can simply set `width` attribute to `auto` instead of fixed `1000px`